# Regex for last sign whitespace if not end of string

Tags: regex, whitespace

I need to get out if the current string ends or has a whitespace

`\\d+(\\s*)(Alpha|Beta){1}(\\s+|$)`

so a digit folllowing by whitespaces or not ... and Alpha or Beta ... and if not end of line, a blank is needed... so `300 Alpha 300 Beta` is possible - but `300 Alpha300 Beta` is not possible or?

Comment: Can you give an example of what your current regex matches that you don't want it to and/or that it doesn't match but should?

Comment: 300 Alpha 300 Beta is not valid

Comment: `{1}` is unnecessary.

Comment: Why isn't `300 Alpha300 Beta` acceptable? Doesn't `300 Beta` end in `$`?

Comment: "300 Alpha300 Beta" is not valid. But "300 Alpha 300 Beta" is valid.
same as " 300 Alpha 300 Beta ".
so whitespace begin end middle is acceptable

Comment: Anyone any idea?

i must catch all Alpha and Betas with the number ....

"300 Alpha 200 Beta" is correct
" 300 Alpha 200 Beta " is correct
" 300 Alpha200 Beta" is wrong because a whitespace after Alpha is needed.... 
"300 Alpha 200 Beta 200 Alpha" is right and so on...

but i hang with the whitespaces in the beginning and end:

Answer (score 0):

A regex like `(^\d+|\s+\d+)(\s+)(Alpha|Beta)` would match:

```
300 Alpha 300 Beta
300 Alpha 300 Beta #with an extra space
300 Alpha 200 Beta 200 Alpha
```

It would *not* match `300 Alpha300 Beta`
[See example](http://regexr.com/3v4da).